# Потеря данных после вызова метода subscribe

Tags: typescript, angular

проблема - вызываю свой метод, который возвращает результат http.get запроса к бд. Возвращаемое значение - id сообщения. это число в методе .subscribe записываю в переменную id, сразу же в теле делаю вывод id в логи - значение есть. Но после отработки метода при повторном выводе в консоль id пуст. В чем причина?

app.component.ts

```
    var id;
    this.dataService.createMess(this.form).subscribe(
        (data: number) => { 
            id = data; 
            console.log(id); //Выводит число
        });
    console.log(id); //Выводит undefined
```

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: @Alpha немного не верно записал код, прошу прощения, отредактировал. переменная `id` создается до вызова метода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)